# convert date from numeric value to date valid format

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to filter all dates which greater than, say 01 january 2011.

```
select * from table_name where date > '01/01/2011';
```

the problem is that `date` field store `int` values, here is an example:

```
1339011098
1336717439
1339010538
```

How to convert the `date` field on the sql query (from the `int` format to date format), I need to convert it to a valid date so that I can compare it towards the above date.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
select * 
from table_name 
where date > unix_timestamp('2011-01-01')
```

Or conversely use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
select * 
from table_name 
where FROM_UNIXTIME(date, "%Y-%m-%d") > '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: I recommend the first query over the second. The second query may be much slower because it will not be able to use an index on the date column (if there is one).

Comment: @IkeWalker - I would consider any performance loss the cost of storing the values as integers instead of date fields. Essentially built in motivation to fix the real issue rather than ignoring it and building on top of it further.

Answer (score 1):

You're going the wrong direction. Rather than converting potentially millions of records for the compare, try converting your target date, which you only need to do once. Those look like unix timestamps, so the resulting query should look like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM `Table_name` WHERE date > unix_timestamp('01/01/2011')
```

Or, if you can control this, try using the ISO date format, which avoids confusion with european date formats for dates like 3/2/13:

```
SELECT  * FROM `Table_name` WHERE date > unix_timestamp('2011-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not store date values as integers and if it's under your control your goal should be to fix the database and any queries that insert an integer value for that column instead of date.

The two date functions that you need to use with the current setup are [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), which accepts a date value and returns the epoch timestamp integer and [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) which accepts an epoch timestamp integer and returns a date value.

For your example, you could use either:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field) > '01/01/2011';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date_field > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01/01/2011');
```

But I would advise using `FROM_UNIXTIME` as a general rule as this would simplify more sophisticated queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field)
BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '04/01/2013';
```

Essentially, until your date field is actually storing values that are date types, your queries should covert the field values with `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Comment: I agree that `TIMESTAMP` would be a better data type choice than `INT` in this case, but I disagree with you about using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` with the current data model. That's a potentially huge performance hit for marginal query simplification.